# Как вызвать jquerry код из aspx.cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Собственно вопрос в заголовке: как вызывать произвольный js код или функцию из aspx.cs файлов?

Comment: звучит странно. вы уверены, что вам нужно именно это? И если да, то зачем?

Comment: Ну окей, давайте попробуем переформулировать задачу вместе: есть asp.net behavior код в aspx.cs файле, если внутри функции переменная принимает значение 0, то должна отработаться одна js функция, а если 1 то другая. Как сформулировать эту задачу иначе?

Comment: ну вообще клиентскому коду место на клиенте. Раз это asp.net, то почему бы вам не сделать именно так, как там это принято - то есть написать нечто вроде 

    if ('<%# Flag %>') {
        одна_функция():
    } else {
        другая();
    }

где  Flag - это ваша переменная из code-behind

Ну либо вообще в code-behinde'у писать скрипты в Response, хотя это несколько коряво

Comment: а в какую переменную лучше это писать? просто в переменную или там в сессию или куда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько способов как я вижу:

1) Зарегистрировать скрипт на странице:

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "return", "alert('Я работаю');", true);`

[How to: Add Client Script Dynamically to ASP.NET Web Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx)

2) hidden поле и в зависимости от значения реагировать кодом на js.